# How to find latest version number of a project from sourceforge.net?

Tags: sourceforge

My package depends on some binary files from `sourceforge.net`, I want to automate building steps, how can I find latest version number to download?

Comment: That depends on the type of version control you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this API will help You

https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Using%20the%20Release%20API/

Comment: thanks, http://sourceforge.net/projects/[projectname]/best_release.json solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Reza commented, you have to parse the output from:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/<projectname>/best_release.json
```

Example:
`curl -qsL "https://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/best_release.json" | sed "s/, /,\n/g" | sed -rn "/release/,/\}/{ /filename/{ 0,//s/([^0-9]*)([0-9\.]+)([^0-9]*.*)/\2/ p }}"`

Further info:
[#260 JSON url for application code to detect when a new release is available.](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/feature-requests/260/)
[#747 allow version metadata for each release](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/feature-requests/747/)