# How to Extract Versions from Software Packages

Tags: python, string, extract

I'm trying to extract the version number from software packages hosted on SourceForge based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263790/how-to-find-latest-version-number-of-a-project-from-sourceforge-net) Stack Overflow post. Specifically, I'm using the [Release API](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Using%20the%20Release%20API/) and the "best_release.json" call. I have the following examples:

- 7-zip: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/best_release.json
- KeePass: https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/best_release.json
- OpenOffice.org:
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/best_release.json

Using the following code snippet:

```
import requests

"""
Un/comment the following lines to change the project name and test
different responses.
"""
proj = "keepass"
# proj = "sevenzip"
# proj = "openofficeorg.mirror"

r = requests.get(f'https://sourceforge.net/projects/{proj}/best_release.json')
json_resp = r.json()
print(json_resp['release']['filename'])
```

I receive the respective results for each package:

- 7-Zip: `/7-Zip/22.00/7z2200-linux-x86.tar.xz`
- KeePass: `/KeePass 2.x/2.51.1/KeePass-2.51.1.zip`
- Openoffice.org: `/extended/iso/en/OOo_3.3.0_Win_x86_install_en-US_20110219.iso`

I'm wondering how I can extract the file versions from these disparate packages. Looking at the results, one can see that there are different naming conventions. For example, 7-Zip puts the file version as "22.00" in the second directory level. KeePass, however, puts it in the second directory level as well as the filename itself. OpenOffice.org puts it inside the filename.

Is there a way to do some sort of fuzzy match that can attempt to extract a "best guess" file version given a filename?

I thought of using regular expressions, [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). For example, I can use the (`\d+`) capture group to capture one or more digits, as demonstrated [here](https://regex101.com/r/l5IsbT/1). However, this would also capture text such as "x86," which I don't want. I just desire some text that looks closest to a version number, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: Versions are arbitrary. This includes format, content, and even order.

Comment: Have you tried the semver regex?  It may find most versions.

Comment: Normally, I'd install in a virtual environment, and then you can use pip freeze to get a list of all the python modules and their versions. You then put that in a requirements file, and install it with something like "pip install -r requirements/base.txt" But if you're just talking about other things installed on your OS, I'm not sure if that's a python question.

Comment: @HEllRZA Will the semver regex find file versions that aren't in the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH style?

Comment: @Alureon No. Thats what i meant with 'most'. You will have to add exceptions for the packages that don't use semver. But I think it would be a good starting point. Then create additional regexes, that handle the missing packages.